# Stuck on XAML code for TreeView With Checkboxes

Tags: c#, xaml, treeview

I have several treeviews that are populated at the code level.
I want to apply checkboxes to them all with minimal code.

i can see the checkboxes and the items names i used to populate the treeviews with no problem however the treeview isnt expanding.

This is the resource Dictionary. i can see that all the settings are being implemented

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:col="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib" 
                xmlns:Primitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit"
                xmlns:ToolKit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit" 
                x:Name="MainDefaultStyle"
                >

<Style TargetType="TreeView">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=ActualHeight}" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=ActualWidth}" />
</Style>
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" x:Name="TreeViewItem">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="AliceBlue" x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrush}"/>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding BindsDirectlyToSource=True}"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding BindsDirectlyToSource=True}"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem" >


                <StackPanel>
                    <CheckBox 
                        x:Name="CheckBox1" 
                        Focusable="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" 
                        Grid.Column="0"

                        >
                            <TextBlock 
                                Margin="1" 
                                Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}},  Path=Header}" 
                                Focusable="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}"
                                Foreground="Black" 
                                Grid.Column="1" 
                                Background="AliceBlue">
                            </TextBlock>
                    </CheckBox>
               </StackPanel>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
 </ResourceDictionary>
```

this is the code in the MainWindow

```
                <TreeView Name="TreeComputers" BorderBrush="Transparent" >
                    <TreeViewItem Header="This is a test" >
                        <TreeViewItem Header="Another test"></TreeViewItem>
                        </TreeViewItem>
                </TreeView>
```

my treeview triggers are created in the code.

```
        TreeComputers.SelectedItemChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<object>(TreeView_SelectionChanged);
        TreeUsers.SelectedItemChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<object>(TreeView_SelectionChanged);
```

Somehow i need to be able to click the items in the treeview that now have the checkbox on them and trigger the routed command..

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem that you can no longer expand items in the tree to see the child items?

I think your problems is that you want to set `TreeView.ItemTemplate` to be a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.

Something like:

```
<Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <StackPanel>
                <CheckBox 
                    x:Name="CheckBox1" 
                    Focusable="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" 
                    Grid.Column="0">
                        <TextBlock 
                            Margin="1" 
                            Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}},  Path=Header}" 
                            Focusable="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}"
                            Foreground="Black" 
                            Grid.Column="1" 
                            Background="AliceBlue">
                        </TextBlock>
                </CheckBox>
           </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate >
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```